# VisualStudio при выводе в консоль всё разъезжается

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

Только учусь программировать на C#, столкнулся с тем, что при объемном выводе всё куда-то съезжает, часть не выводится.
Переустанавливал всё, результат один и тот же, при том на компе жены все работает как надо, даже если код просто скопировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вы для вывода используете `Console.WriteLine`, который выводит в консоль переданные данные, после чего **перенос строки**. Предполагаю, что Вам надо взглянуть на `Console.Write`.

Comment: Точно, видимо устал и не заметил, спасибо большое))